# Java compatible English Dictionary API?

Tags: java

I am trying to mimic a simple news reader, a desktop application developed on swings. As a part of this I am looking at including a dictionary lookup for a word from within the tool. I am looking at trying to display the meaning for word as a tool tip that appears upon a double click on JTextpane's content(one single word).

So is there an exposed API for dictionary look-up? Also considering the fact that I am using java swings, the speed with which the API performs dictionary look up is also a key concern in my case..

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to a table of words and meanings.  Once you have that the rest should be straight forward.

For a dictionary loop, you could use a Dictionary class, but I would use LinkedHashMap<String, String> to store words and meanings.  This will take less than one micro-second to do the lookup `get()`, which should be fast enough.