# English dictionary class for java Eclipse

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a list of words which I would want to check if they are present in the dictionary or not. I am using Eclipse, so, does Java have an English dictionary class (list of words) that I can use, or are there open source implementations of this?

Comment: It is not very clear if you want to use the dictionary in your implementation or if you need to check the spelling of your source code (as Eclipse have a built-in spell-checker)

Answer (score 1):

[Programming] language systems generally don't have built-in word dictionaries, to my knowledge. Think of the sheer size for including such things in even a few languages!

This thread may help: [Java compatible English Dictionary API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510620/java-compatible-english-dictionary-api)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a list of words in one language, there are many resources on Internet often related to hacking (password guess through dictionnary attack is quite common).

The first search could be done as well on the stackoverflow site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741003/a-text-file-with-a-list-of-words

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at something like a spell checker to accomplish this - if the word is spelled correctly, it's in the dictionary.  Depending on your license requirements/restrictions, [Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/) might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: In my case, I want to iterate over a list of words and form new ones, rather than just lookup words that are already typed. So a spell checker would not work for me (but I know the asker did specify spell-checking).